# R | How to get accuracy from cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glm, lasso-regression

I've been using the `cv.glmnet` function to fit a lasso logistic regression model. I'm using `R`

Here's my code. I'm using the `iris` dataset.

```
df = iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  filter(!(Species =="setosa")) %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.factor(Species))
  
X = data.matrix(df %>% select(-Species))
y = df$Species

Model = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
```

How do I get the model accuracy from the `cv.glmnet` object (Model).

If I had been using caret on a normal logistic regression model, accuracy is already in the output.

```
train_control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
M2 = train(Species ~., data = df, trControl = train_control, 
           method = "glm", family = "binomial")
M2$results
```

but a `cv.glmnet` object doesn't seem to contain this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `type.measure='class'` as in Model 2 below, otherwise the default for `family='binomial'` is `'deviance'`.

```
df = iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% 
  filter(!(Species =="setosa")) %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.factor(Species))

X = data.matrix(df %>% select(-Species))
y = df$Species

Model  = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
Model2 = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", type.measure = 'class')
```

Then `cvm` gives the misclassification rate.

```
Model2$lambda ## lambdas used in CV
Model2$cvm    ## mean cross-validated error for each of those lambdas
```

If you want results for the best lambda, you can use `lambda.min`

```
Model2$lambda.min ## lambda with the lowest cvm
Model2$cvm[Model2$lambda==Model2$lambda.min] ## cvm for lambda.min
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just wondering, is this misclassification rate a good indicator for model assessment. Or should I be using a more training vs testing data approach.

Comment: Do you know how to also extract the confusion matrix?

Comment: train/testing would be best, especially if you're comparing with other models

Comment: for the confusion matrix, see `confusion.glmnet` here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.0-2/topics/assess.glmnet